# wordpress is auto using http: not https: as it needs to because the server is http behind a reverse proxy https, how do I stop it?

Tags: ssl, https, nginx

I am installing `wordpress 6.2` and this is my install screen

[image]

as you can see there is something wrong, then I realised what it is

[image]

when you look at the source wordpress is (correctly) working out the server is only `http:`  which technically it is, but this is just a LAN server `192.168.0.10` behind a gateway `192.168.0.1`. In reality this gateway machine handles the ssl and certs and forwards it to port 80 via nginx reverse proxy.

This means that the worpdress site "thinks" it's internal references are all on on `http:` but actually the links will NOT work unless they are `https:` because the gateway won't forward them

How do I fx it so that the source says

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='buttons-css' href='https://SOMEMADEUPDOMAIN.com/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=6.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='forms-css' href='https://SOMEMADEUPDOMAIN.com/wp-admin/css/forms.min.css?ver=6.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='l10n-css' href='https://SOMEMADEUPDOMAIN.com/wp-admin/css/l10n.min.css?ver=6.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='install-css' href='https://SOMEMADEUPDOMAIN.com/wp-admin/css/install.min.css?ver=6.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

**PS**: I have tried adding

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false ) {
   $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

towards the bottom of `wp-config.php` but it's having none of it

Comment: have you tried using HTTPS all the way instead of terminating it at your proxy? This sounds like a proxy issue. Also `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` is for admin, but your screenshot shows an installer page

Comment: What are `home` and `siteurl` set to in your database's `{$prefix}options` table? If they're set to `http://example.com`, change them to `https://example.com`.

Comment: @PatJ I'm still at the install stage, it isn't referencing the db yet

Comment: @TomJNowell if you terminate the internal server at ssl you're adding a layer of self signing that is totally unneeded. It's the wrong solution

Comment: I see you have `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` but have you confirmed that it is indeed present and set? How is your proxy implemented? Doing this is possible without modifying WP core

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a fix, I am not happy with it but it works:

I added `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);`  to `wp-config.php`

Then I changed this method `is_ssl()` in `/wp-includes/load.php` to this. I think to avoid this bug, the `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` check should have be used by the developers.

I added the line `if( defined( FORCE_SSL_ADMIN ) ) return FORCE_SSL_ADMIN;`

```
/**
 * Determines if SSL is used.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 * @since 4.6.0 Moved from functions.php to load.php.
 *
 * @return bool True if SSL, otherwise false.
 */
function is_ssl() {
    if( defined( FORCE_SSL_ADMIN ) ) return FORCE_SSL_ADMIN;
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
        if ( 'on' === strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        if ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) {
            return true;
        }
    } elseif ( isset( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) && ( '443' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**PS:** I think it ***is*** a bug because the code does not operate under a principle know as [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth)

Comment: If you change core code, you will lose your changes at the next WP core update. You need to re-think your solution (which is currently over my head) to not having changes to WP core code.

Comment: @RickHellewell yes it's not ideal to patch it, but the alternative is a dead website I'll submit it as a bug

Comment: @RickHellewell my change means that the actual defined value `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` is used whether or not it "self detects" http, which is I think ) how it should work based on it being optional, and it having the name: **FORCE**

Answer (score 0):

You need to let wordpress know, it was accessed via https using the `X-Forwarded-Proto` http header.

I have the following in my nginx (=proxy) config

```
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```